# UILabel UILongPressGestureRecognizer not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

How can I get the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on uilabel.when i implement the following code it doesn't call the function. So please tell me what wrong i did ?

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LabelLongPressed:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;  // Seconds
longPress.numberOfTapsRequired = 0;

[objlblDuplicate addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
[longPress release];
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By default UILabel is not able to get touch events.

```
objlblDuplicate.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: LongPressedGesture is recognized twice though. First time is when long press happens, and the second time is when long press is released from the finger.