# Swift, UILongPressGestureRecognizer Not working in UIlabel

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I am trying long press Gesture in Swift for Copy Option.

But it is not working. It is not identifying the Gesture in UiView Or UILabel either.

**Below is my Code**

*In View DidLoad*

```
     let copyLongPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ContactDetailController.handleLongPress(_:)))
    copyLongPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 0
    copyLongPress.delegate = self
    copyLongPress.minimumPressDuration=0.5
    self.lblDynaMobile.addGestureRecognizer(copyLongPress)
    self.lblDynaMobile.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.lblDynaDDI.addGestureRecognizer(copyLongPress)
     self.lblDynaDDI.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.GeneralView.addGestureRecognizer(copyLongPress)
    self.EmailView.addGestureRecognizer(copyLongPress)
    self.AddressView.addGestureRecognizer(copyLongPress)
```

*New Mothod*

```
func handleLongPress(longPressView :UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let lblFont:UILabel = (longPressView.view as? UILabel)!
    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = lblFont.text

}
```

I have added UIGestureRecognizerDelegate too in the Declaration of  class

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613118/uilabel-uilongpressgesturerecognizer-not-working?rq=1

Comment: @sanmanborate, i have already done that..but not working..    self.lblDynaMobile.userInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: @dhavalshah, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929703/why-does-uitableviews-swipe-delete-sometimes-work-fine-sometimes-not/20157326#20157326

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and see (it's working.)

```
// in viewDidLoad()
let copyLongPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPress(_:)))
self.lblDynaMobile.addGestureRecognizer(copyLongPress)

func handleLongPress(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if let lblFont = gesture.view as? UILabel {
      //UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = lblFont.text
    }

}
```